# How to add the overlay for the background image

Tags: html, css

I want to add an overlay over the div which has the background image. the divs will be generated from the php. Each div will have an background image.

When i try to add the gradient overlay on top of the div having background image, i couldn't see any changes happening.

How can i do this?

here is what i have tried

Html

```
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/stacks.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/random.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/laos.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/thai.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/phils.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(images/tabs.jpg);"></div>
```

Css

```
.image-box:hover{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.1),rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.4),rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.8));
}
```

Comment: Is this is what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/cd8g7wz9/

Comment: @HelloWorld Yeah, but with hover effect

Comment: Is this one solves? https://jsfiddle.net/7otxupsc/ Overlay displays only on hover..

Comment: @HelloWorld thanks at the same time i'm also able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

May this will help you. Try it:

Initially, I have added a pseudo-element `::after` which acts as an overlay and assigned the size same as `image-box` and initially its `display: none;` but on hover changed to `display: block;` which applies the overlay on hover only.

```css
.image-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image-box::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.1),rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.4),rgba(9, 37, 70, 0.8));
    content: '';
}
.image-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image-box:hover::after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
<div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320__340.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: You could explain a bit how your solution works. It might not be obvious for the OP or for someone else reading this :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my post and explained my solution.